# I have a 1 to many mapping, how can I map back to the parent object?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4.1

I have a mapping like:

```
public class Order
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public virtual ICollection<Item> Items {get;set;}
}

public class Item
{
   public int Id;
   public int OrderId;
}
```

I mapped them using:

```
public class OrderConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Order>
{
  public OrderConfiguration()
  {
       this.HasKey(x => x.Id);
       this.HasMany(x => x.Items).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(v => v.OrderId);
  }
}
```

But now I want to be able to do this (for read-only operations, I won't make updates to this):

```
someItem.Order
```

How can I change my mapping to allow for this?

Also, if I load say 100 items, is it possible to eager load the Order graph for all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Item
{
   public int Id;
   public int OrderId;
   public virtual Order Order { get; set; } 
}
```

I don't understand what you mean by graph. But you could do this

```
context.Items.Include(e => e.Order).Where(e => filter100(e)).ToList();
```

That should eager load Orders as well.

Comment: Well, it's not that simple. It will work because you called the foreign key OrderID that is EntityClassNameID. Because of that EF knows that this is foreign key to Order. If you add another Order property, this will stop working and you will have to specify foreign keys using annotations or fluent API. Also if you change the name of OrderID it will stop working. But I recommend sticking to convention as often as possible.

Comment: how can I explicitly set the FK if it is different? (using fluent api)

Comment: modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().HasRequired(s => s.Order).WithMany(e => e.Items).HasForeignKey(s => s.YourForeignKeyForOrder); This syntax does make sense it works like that: You start with Item -> HasREquireed -> now you're at order -> (so order has) withMany -> you're back at item -> item.hasForeignKey ;)